# How to add symbols on smooth lines in a R's lattice xyplot?

Tags: r, data-visualization

In a lattice xyplot with multiple smooth curves, I plotted curves categorized by color (y1, y2, y3 in blue; z1, z2, z3 in red).

If we consider the following simple data :

```
x<-1:50
y1<-rnorm(50,100,20)
y2<-rnorm(50,80,20)
y3<-rnorm(50,90,20)
z1<-rnorm(50,60,20)
z2<-rnorm(50,40,20)
z3<-rnorm(50,65,20)
```

we can make such a plot with smooth lines and specify colors with this code:

```
xyplot(y1+y2+y3+z1+z2+z3~x,type='smooth', span=0.4,
par.settings=list(superpose.line=list(col=c('blue','blue','blue','red','red','red'))))
```

and we get this result:

[image: multiple smooth curves]

My question : **Do you know how to add symbol (markers) on each curves to identify it ?**

For instance, y1 with a triangle marker in blue, y2 with a square marker in blue, etc.

It is easy to do this when raw data is plotted, but I can't find how to do it with smooth curves. I tried to use `superpose.symbol` but it seems that it's works only when `type=c('p','smooth')`. But in this case, symbols are not on the curves but in the raw positions.

NB. I tried to identify the curves with different line type (cf. `lty`) but but the result does not allow a good visualization with my data.

Comment: This IMO is better suited for SO, did you check out the [lattice questions over there](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%5Blattice%5D+label). Some examples over there may be pertinent to your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve this:

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)

my.df <- data.frame(y=c(y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3), 
                    g=gl(6, 50), x=rep(x, 6))

my.panel.loess <- function(x, y, span=2/3, ...) {
  loess.fit <- loess.smooth(x, y, span=span)
  panel.lines(loess.fit$x, loess.fit$y, ...)
}

pp <- list()
pp[[1]] <- xyplot(y ~ x, data=my.df, groups=g, type="b", 
                  col=rep(c("blue","red"), each=3), cex=.6, 
                  panel=function(...) 
                    panel.superpose(panel.groups=my.panel.loess, ...))

pp[[2]] <- update(pp[[1]], span=1/5)
pp[[3]] <- update(pp[[1]], col=1:6, type=c("p", "g"))
pp[[4]] <- update(pp[[1]], pch=rep(c(2,6), each=3))

do.call(grid.arrange,  pp)
```

You will notice that I had to briefly define a custom panel function for the smoother. This is because I need to pass an extra parameter to `panel.lines` (`"p"`+`"l"`=`"b"`); note that it cannot be used directly when calling `panel.lines` since this formal parameter is already defined in `xyplot`.

The rest of the code is pure drawing with varying parameters (all digested through the `...` argument). Although I arranged your data in a more convenient `data.frame`, I believe your original formulation will work with slight adaptation around the call to `panel.groups`.

[image]

However, you can annotate the curves directly with the [directlabels](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/directlabels/index.html) package (a lot of [examples](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/) are available on R-forge). Something along those lines should work fine:

```
library(directlabels)
pp0 <- xyplot(y ~ x, data=my.df, groups=g, type="smooth") 
direct.label(pp0, "follow.points")
```

I should note that there is a nice function, `labcurve()`, in the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package that does pretty much the same job.

Comment: `labcurve` is called by the Hmisc package's `xYplot` function to make this even easier.